# Count elements before an element

Tags: jquery

here is an example :

```
<div class="create-q"></div>
<div class="create-q"></div>
<div class="create-q"></div>
<div class="create-q"></div> <-- im in this class : I want to know how many div with class "create-q" there is before this one. (3 in this example)
<div class="create-q"></div>
<div class="create-q"></div>
```

I know how to count but not how to stop it once it reach a specified div..

How can I do this with jQuery ?

Comment: By the way, you are not `in that class`, but  you are in `that element`. You haven't shown how `you got there`.

Comment: From the example above, how do you determine which div you want to count elements before and after? They all are identical. How do you select the target div?

Comment: You can stop by placing a 'break;' statement in your loop.

Comment: Yes sorry I'm in an element not a class...

Comment: My div are actually a list of questions. When I insert a new question, it creates a new div, I need to count the number of div before the new one, to know the number (is it in 1st 2nd 3rd etc.. position ?) of the new question.

Comment: I repeat, show *how* you got there: click event, random selection, etc.

Comment: Do you not always add new questions to the _end_ of the list?

Comment: My problem is now solved by Alnitak. But I drag and drop quuestion where I want in the form, this is why I have to do this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If `mydiv` is a reference to the element you're already looking at:

```
var n = $(mydiv).index('.create-q');
```

will give the index of that div which as they're zero-based also happens to be the number of preceding divs.

Unlike `.prevAll()` this will work regardless of whether the divs have a common parent or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery's [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) method,

if `currentelem` is the reference to your element then,

```
$(currentelem).prevAll().length
```

Would give you the number of elements before your element within the same parent or container.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the target element just do:

`$(this).prev(".create-q").length` and `$(this).next(".create-q").length`

Answer (score -1):

you can use Loop through selected elements with jQuery

[reference  Example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/loop-through-selected-elements-jquery-revised/)

[reference JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/kq4K8/)

```
<div id="example">
<div  class="create-q">1</div>
<div  class="create-q">2</div>
<div  class="create-q">3</div>
<div  class="create-q">thisOne</div>
<div class="create-q">5</div>
<div  class="create-q">6</div>
</div>
```

```
function example(thisOne) {
    var count=0;
    var hrefs = '';  
    $('#example div').each(function(idx, item) {  
        //alert(item); return object HTMLDivElement
        hrefs += item.innerHTML+ '\n' ;  
        count+=1;
        if(item.innerHTML==thisOne)
        {
//this is what you want the nubmber of elements before thisOne
            alert(count-1);
            return 0;
        }
    });
    window.alert(hrefs);

}
```