# Count elements before a specific class in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to count all classes with the name "**loader**" ***before*** the class "**p16**" (for example).

In this case the right answer would be: **4**

```
<div class="loader p12"></div>

<div class="loader p13"></div>

<div class="loader p14"></div>

<div class="loader p15"></div>

<div class="loader p16"></div>

<div class="loader p17"></div>

<div class="loader p18"></div>
```

I tried serveral solutions:

```
var $slides = $('.loader');
var $current = $slides.find('.p5');

var index = $slides.index($current) + 1;
var total = $slides.length;

var n = $('.loader').index('.p5');
alert(n);
alert(index);
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mc184j7f/

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count elements before an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832649/count-elements-before-an-element)

Comment: I found this other topic too but this topic was with a parent class and mine was with the same element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```js
console.log($('.p16').prevAll('.loader').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader p12"></div>
<div class="loader p13"></div>
<div class="loader p14"></div>
<div class="loader p15"></div>
<div class="loader p16"></div>
<div class="loader p17"></div>
<div class="loader p18"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works very well. I will accept this answer, because you were the first.

Comment: NB: this does assume that all of the `loader` elements are siblings.

Comment: Assuming they are not siblings then you would need to use the index method charlietfl has provided, but if you are only wanting previous siblings, I would use this one as the index way may pick up other loaders that are not siblings, unless you had a more specific selector

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the elements in the document that have the `loader` class and then stop when you reach `p16`.

```
var total = 0
$('.loader').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("p16")){
    return false;
  }
  total++;
});
```

Comment: This will count all of them, not just the ones before the current.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `index()` incorrectly.

Pass in an element or jquery object to index that specific element within the collection

```js
console.log($('.loader').index($('.p16')))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader p12"></div>
<div class="loader p13"></div>
<div class="loader p14"></div>
<div class="loader p15"></div>
<div class="loader p16"></div>
<div class="loader p17"></div>
<div class="loader p18"></div>
```